# Unable to share photos

Tags: android-11

I just "upgraded" my Pixel3a to 11. Now I can't share photos from my piktures (yes, that is how it's spelled) photo management app via Messages or Gmail. Tapping the share button presents only two options: 'Nearby share' and 'bluetooth'. In Android 10, I was greeted with many apps.

I was able to briefly get Messages and Gmail to show up in the list by going to those apps and attaching photos from there. Alas, those apps are no longer visible from piktures. The problem with attaching photos from those apps is that they show the newest photos first. While that is often the right answer, sometimes I want to share an older photo and it is very tedious to scroll and scroll in the hopes of finding it.

As a side note, I can no longer delete photos from piktures either.

Is there a setting somewhere that allows me to share from piktures?

Comment: Starting with Android 11 apps have to use the new Scoped Storage API for accessing files on the sd-card section. piktures claims to be ready for Android11 (targetSdkVersion=30) but it still tries to use the legacy mode (requestLegacyExternalStorage=true) which will no longer work on Android 11. Therefore any file access problems are a bug that have to be fixed by the developer(s).

Comment: @Robert, the Pixel 3a does not accept an sd-card. Perhaps the Scoped Storage applies to main memory as well.

Comment: @Robert legacy storage works on Android 11 too but in different way. Though Google strongly disapproves its usage: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage#all-files-access

Comment: @IrfanLatif Thanks for the info. In this case however piktures app does not request `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in it's manifest, hence if I understand it correctly it does not make use of this way.